# 'put' in SFTP using Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I've installed and written the following Paramiko which is unable to put the file. It is easily able to 'get' a file and execute `ls` commands on it.

```
#set username & password
username='runaway'
password='runaway'
port=22
source= '/Unzip.sh' 
destination ='/var/mpx/www/http'


#SFTP
client.load_system_host_keys()
print " hostname =%s \n username=%s \n password=%s \n" (hostname,username,password)
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port)) 
t.connect(username=username,password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.put(source,destination)
#sftp.close()
#t.close()
```

Using a 'put' command gives the following error & stack trace -

```
File "upload_file.py", line 84, in ?
    sftp.put(source,destination)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 522, in put
    fr = self.file(remotepath, 'wb')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 221, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 572, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 619, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 649, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
IOError: Failure
```

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The solution seemed very funny to me!

```
source= '/Unzip.sh' 
destination ='/var/mpx/www/http/Unzip.sh'
```

Just modified the destination path to include the file name as well.
Didn't expect some error like this coming from a Python package.

Comment: you could maybe patch paramiko in that respect ;)  i.e. so it does understand destination-folders.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

This also occurs in 2.0.2 when you try to `sftp.mkdir('/exists')`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 380, in mkdir
    self._request(CMD_MKDIR, path, attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 730, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 781, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 811, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
IOError: Failure
```

This was my Python 2.7.9 fix:

```
try:
    sftp.mkdir(remote_dir)
except IOError:
    logging.debug('%s already exists.', remote_dir)
```