# SSHClient paramiko Python?

Tags: python, ssh, module

I use this method to send file to remote server:

```
def runSendArchive(host, port, username, password, remote_directory, archive):
    try:
        s = paramiko.SSHClient()
        s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        s.connect(host, username, password, port)

        sftp = s.open_sftp()
        sftp.put(archive, remote_directory)
        print "3 - The file was uploaded via SSH!"

    except (BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException, socket.error) as e:
        print "4 - Error! The file was not uploaded: ", e
```

It returns me an exception:

> ```
> except (BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException, socket.error) as e: NameError: global name
> ```
>
> 'BadHostKeyException' is not defined

How to use this library right?

Now I get the following error:

```
File "run.py", line 65, in runSendArchive
    sftp.put(archive, remote_directory)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 721, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 677, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, 'wb') as fr:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 338, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 774, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 826, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 859, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
IOError: Failure
```

65 line is `sftp.put(archive, remote_directory)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the line

```
paramiko.SSHClient()
```

you are calling `import paramiko`

Since `BadHostKeyException` is in `paramiko.ssh_exception`, you need to add an

```
from paramiko.ssh_exception import BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException
```

See http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.3/api/ssh_exception.html

- paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException
- paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException
- paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException

reside in that module.

For your example code snippet you would need to add the following before the `runSendArchive` function

```
import socket
import paramiko
from paramiko.ssh_exception import BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException
```

Comment: I tried import: `import paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException`

Comment: It gives me: `    import paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException
ImportError: No module named AuthenticationException`

Comment: `from paramiko.ssh_exception import BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException`

Comment: `NameError: global name 'socket' is not defined`

Comment: `import socket`

Comment: See question again, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091326/put-in-sftp-using-paramiko --> `remote_directory` should  be `remote_path` (including new filename on server, ie `/home/user/upload.txt`)